# turn of outliers boxplot in python

Tags: python, boxplot

Any ideas on how to turn of the outliers for the box plot?
Or send a link to the documentation for kind="box" because I've not been able to find it

Code is:

```
    df9=df.ix[Month+"-2015":Month+"-2015"]
    df9=df9.rename(columns={'hour_mean': "2015"})


    x=pd.concat([df1['2004'],df2['2005'],df3['2006'],df4['2007'],df5['2008'],df6['2012'],df7['2013'],df8['2014'],df9['2015']],axis=1)


    ax=x.plot(kind="box")
```

Because its plotting out a series of series: Seemed to be the only way of doing a box plot. So it plots it for 2004 then 2005etc.

x looks like:

```
Date    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008
01/12/2004 00:00    9.8             
01/12/2004 01:00    4.5             
01/12/2004 02:00    2.7             
01/12/2004 03:00    5.7             
01/12/2004 04:00    10.7                
01/12/2004 05:00    10.2                
01/12/2004 06:00    11.3                
01/12/2004 07:00    7.3             
01/12/2004 08:00    7.2             
01/12/2004 09:00    6.6             
01/12/2004 10:00    9.7             
01/12/2004 11:00    1.7             
01/12/2004 12:00    3.3             
01/12/2004 13:00    8.8             
01/12/2004 14:00    5.4             
01/12/2004 15:00    8.5             
01/12/2004 16:00    1.9             
01/12/2004 17:00    3.1             
01/12/2004 18:00    6.1             
01/12/2004 19:00    -4.1                
01/12/2004 20:00    4.8             
01/12/2004 21:00    2.1             
01/12/2004 22:00    2.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 ax=x.plot(kind="box", showfliers=False)
```

Outliers in pyplot are called fliers. Check this [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot).